# when outbound adapter fails to open destination queue , messages are lost from source

Tags: jms, spring-integration, spring-jms, spring-io

I have Inbound Message Listener adapter and when outbound adapter fails to open destination queue , messages are lost from source queue. I am using spring-io for jms queue message transfer.

How to commit the transfer after the message reaches destination queue or else stays in source queue?

Answer (score 0):

Set `acknowledge="transacted"` on the `message-driven-channel-adapter`.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a transaction propagation issue from consumer to producer. You can fix it easily by doing the below additional configurations.

If you are using `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`, It is strongly recommended to either set sessionTransacted to true or specify an external transactionManager.

If you did not configured a message listener container but using `message-driven-channel-adapter` instead, you need to set its `acknowledge` property to `transacted`.

To configure your outbound adapter to participate in transaction, you need to configure `JmsTemplate` as follows and set its `sessionTransacted` property to `true`:

```
<bean id="outboundJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="outboundCF" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="outboundDestination" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
</bean>
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="jmsOutChannel" jms-template="outboundJmsTemplate" />
```

Hope it will solve your problem.